# Can you access an element in CSS by referring to its child element?

Tags: html, css

So I have a basic table, in which some of the `<td>` tags consist of a `div` defined by a class called "chapter-div".

Is there a way I could access only the `<td>`s which have the "chapter-div" divisions inside of them (USING ONLY THIS TRAIT OF THEM), excluding all of the others `td`s?

For perception purposes, if we can do this in CSS:

```
td > .chapter-div
```

What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
td < .chapter-div
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what have I just read... Your markup and stylesheet is utterly wrong if you want to do this kind of selecting an element.

Comment: It's not possible in CSS. Solution: add a class to the td itself if it contains such an element. You could do that using JavaScript, but personally I think this is a server side issue that should be solved when generating the page.

Comment: What a nice person you seem to be, @knitevision.

Answer (score 0):

This can only be achieved with Javascript. If you're using jQuery, its pretty simple:

```
$('.chapter-div').parent().addClass('chapter-div-parent');
```

Then you can style your td with the .chapter-div-parent class.

Comment: Thank you! The reason why I asked this question is because someone asked me so modify his code using only these traits. I'll use your solution.